# GridView dose not show all items in a wrap_content height Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

### [SOVLED]

The Solution for those need : replace the `Gridview` with `Recyclerview` and use this method to calculate the "auto_fit" rows for `Gridview` . set `Gridview` item layout size to `wrap_content` with attribute `adjustViewBounds="true"` for the images.

```
 public int calculateNoOfColumns(Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        int noOfColumns = (int) (dpWidth / 180);
        return noOfColumns;
    }
```

The problem is when I set the wrap_content height for the `LinearLayout`, the `GridView` doesn't show all items ( just a half ). It works if the layout_height is match_parent, but each item will have a lot of space. (I use `recyclerview` with `HasFixedSize(true)`. the `GridView` will show all items if  height and width are fixed size

### This is the Layout contains Recyclerview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.Chat">

//APPBAR LAYOUT HERE. BUT DOES NOT MATTER

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:stackFromEnd="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

   //SOME VIEWS HERE BUT NOT IMPORTANT

</RelativeLayout>
```

### this is the code of RecyclerView

```
mLayoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
Recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
Recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
Recycler.setAdapter(Adapter);
Recycler.setItemAnimator(null);
```

### this is the RecyclerView Item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   //more views here but not important

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </GridView>

                <ImageView
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### this is the grid view item and grid view adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/img_row_multiple_media"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/playbutton_row_multiple_media"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_button"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int mIndex, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        mViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView==null){
            viewHolder=new mViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiple_media,null);
            viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_row_multiple_media);
            viewHolder.playbutton=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.playbutton_row_multiple_media);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else viewHolder = (mViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        if (mList.get(mIndex).getType().equalsIgnoreCase(MessagesUtils.MESSAGE_TYPE_PICTURE))
            viewHolder.playbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else  viewHolder.playbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        if (mList.get(mIndex).getLink_thumb_media()!=null) {
            Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(mList.get(mIndex).getLink_thumb_media())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);

        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: do you need HasFixedSize? does the issue occur when hasFixedSize is set to false?

Comment: let me try.thanks. But if you dont set HasfixedSize to true. the performance will not good

Comment: you need to paste code for what is inside GridView. In code sample GridView is empty

Comment: which part do you need ? I will post

Comment: what is in your GridView.
Preferably whole view would be great - easier to debug when I can put it in my test app

Comment: there are some images, sir. nothing special. just 1 "main" image and 1 "play button"

Comment: manage through  android:layout_weight property in grid view and others. LinearLayout height set match_parent.

Comment: as the title. it will work if I set layout_height of LinearLayout to match_parent, but each item will have a lot of space

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

MORE VIEWS HERE BUT IT DOES NOT MATTER.

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/layout_media">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:id="@+id/multiple_media_list"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/message_picture"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:minHeight="150dp"
                            android:minWidth="150dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/playbutton"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_button"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"/>
                    </GridView>
                </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that your GridView was empty in code you've pasted. Images you said supposed to be in it, was outside of closing tab.

Comment: I dont talk about those images, I talk about the items of gridview . gridview contains some of imagesviews but they are not showed up

Comment: so - long story short - show whole layout code, or noone will help you. do not say, that something is not important - you clearly have messed up XML, so everything is important. please, have respect for ppl wiling to help you

Comment: I have showed you everthing that relate to the problem. everything else works fine and the problem just happen with the Gridview. I dont have to hide anything from anyone. I just wanna give you more and more detail about this problem

Comment: I have testing and solving it all night and I gave you everything that I think them relate to the problem

Comment: Like I said, if you want me to post any part of codes, I will do it for you